# Why shadow is reflecting on child subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, shadow

I have a view in which I am applying shadow programmetically. But unfortunately this shadow appears on all the subviews of this particular view. Any reason of that.

```
    cellView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    cellView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    cellView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    cellView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    cellView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0

    timeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: self.bounds.size.height - 30))
    timeLabel.font = AmeyoConstants.smallerFont
    timeLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    cellView.addSubview(timeLabel)
```

I had applied shadow only on cellView but on running the app, shadow automatically appears on timeLabel also. Can anyone let me know the proper reason of inheritence of shadow from parent to child views.

Comment: set `cellView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white`. Shadow is reflecting to subviews because of clear color

Comment: where you put this code

Comment: instead of `cellView.layer` use only `cellView`

Comment: @Priya: It worked. Thanks a lot. I was bypassing it with UIColor.clear.

Comment: Thank you @priya. it is worked . I forgot to add bg color.

Answer (score 12):

For a view to have a shadow, it must have an opaque background color, we can't see from your snippet but did you set a background color to `cellView`?

If not then the shadow will be applied not to the view itself but to its subviews instead!

If you think about it, a transparent sheet of paper has no shadow (because it's transparent of course), but if you add opaque objects on it then these objects will have a shadow.

Now if you want the sheet to have a shadow instead then you'd put an opaque sheet right? Well the same rules apply to iOS in this case!

Comment: great example to understand this issue.

Comment: Eventhough I am using SwiftUI but this answer saved me!

Comment: this answer should be marked correct.